# EF 6.2 code first, simple query takes very long

Tags: performance, entity-framework, ef-code-first

In an old DB application I'd like to start moving towards code first approach.

There are a lot of SPs, triggers, functions, etc. in the database which make things error prone.

As a starter, I'd like to have a proof of concept, therefore I started with a new solution, where I imported the entire database (Add new item -> ADO.NET entity data model -> Code First from database)

As a simple first shot I wanted to query 1 column of 1 table. The table contains about 5k rows and the result delivers 3k strings. This takes over 90 seconds now!

Here's the code of the query:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var db = new Model1())
        {
            var theList = db.T_MyTable.AsNoTracking()
                .Where(t => t.SOME_UID != null)
                .OrderBy(t => t.SOMENAME)
                .Select(t => t.SOMENAME)
                .ToList();
            foreach (var item in theList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Number of names: " + theList.Count());
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

In the generated table code I added the column type "VARCHAR" to all of the string fields/column properties:

```
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")] // this I added to all of the string properties
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string SOME_UID { get; set; }
```

I assume I miss out an important step, can't believe code first query is so slow.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the root cause is the huge context that needs to be built, existing of over 1000 tables/files.

How I found the problem: using the profiler I observed that the expected query hits the database after about 90 seconds, telling me that the query itself is fast. Then I tried the same code in a new project, where I only imported the single table I access in the code.

Another proof that it's context related is executing the query twice in the same session; the second time was executed in the milliseconds.

**Key point:** if you have a legacy database with a lot of tables, don't use 1 single DbContext that contains all the tables (except for initializing the database), but several smaller domain specific ones with the tables you need for the given domain context. Entities can exist in multiple DbContexts, taylor the relationships (e.g. by "Ignore"-ing where not required) and do lazy loading where appropriate. These things help to boost performance.